# If he did this he will be punished. Is it OK?

Tags: conditionals

A person is talking about a suspect. It is not clear for the moment whether or not they have violated the law. The person makes a statement about the future:

> If he did this he will be punished.

Is it grammatically correct? What type of conditionals is this?

Answer (score 0):

There are no problems with that sentence.

Wikipedia calls that kind of conditional sentence a [factual conditional sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#Implicative_and_predictive):

> A conditional sentence expressing an *implication* (also called a *factual* conditional sentence) essentially states that if one fact holds, then so does another. [...] The facts are usually stated in whatever grammatical tense is appropriate to them; there are not normally special tense or mood patterns for this type of conditional sentence.